Where can I find the Soviet Red Star Newspaper where Col. Galkin published about Japanese biological warfare?
In the book Unit 731: Testimony, Hal Gold states on Page 88

In July 1948, the Soviet army newspaper Red Star carried an article by a Col. Galkin, special correspondent on the newspaper for Japanese biological warfare. According to the article, the Japanese were preparing to use biological warfare on a large scale, and they had a huge bacteriological center in Manchuria. Galkin's piece did not state that Japanese biological warfare was intended for use against his country, and instead specifically pointed out that it was for use against China, the United States, and Britain. The Red Star article also did not mention Soviet citizens as victims of human experimentation. Still more surprising, the Soviet article did not mention the imperial order which had allegedly led to the establishment of the labs. There was only mention of Prince Mikasa acting as the emperor's representative.

(Bold mine)
I am quite lost on how to find the Red Star newspaper that the book talks about. I would appreciate any links to this, that either

Is the direct primary source, or
Is a secondary source confirming the above


WIkipedia:RedStar has links to archives for the newspaper. Have you checked there? Where have you looked?

Does Gold not do footnotes? Knowing the publication date and/or page of the newspaper would help.

FAS footnote points to potentially helpful "261 Andrey Poleshchuk, “Interview With SVR Director
Vyacheslav Trubnikov,” Nezavisimaya Gazeta, 18
December 1996, pp. 1-2; “Yeltsin Admits Russians
Engage in Economic Espionage, Counterintelligence
News and Digest, National Counterintelligence Center,
Vol. 1, March 1996; Jeff Stein, “I, Spy Cold Warriors No
More, Russian Spies Languish in Irrelevance."

Japanese War Crimes Documents might help

@MCW Unfortunately the official archive is extremely spotty.

@MCW, the Japanese War Crimes Documents do have a table entry for this (Location 290/10/35/03), I think, but have not verified this yet. Thank you.
